# group by clause help

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am coding facebook kind request page for a project. I am stuck with grouping requests in all requests printed page.

my sql as

```
SQL = "SELECT R.REQUESTID, R.BYID, R.TOID, R.TYPE, R.DATEENTERED, M.MEMBERID, M.FIRSTNAME, M.LASTNAME"
SQL = SQL & " FROM REQUESTS R, MEMBERS M"
SQL = SQL & " WHERE R.ACTIVE = 1 AND R.TOID = "& Session("MEMBERID") &" AND R.BYID = M.MEMBERID"
SQL = SQL & " GROUP BY R.REQUESTID, R.BYID, R.TOID, R.TYPE, R.DATEENTERED, M.MEMBERID, M.FIRSTNAME, M.LASTNAME"
SQL = SQL & " ORDER BY R.DATEENTERED DESC"
```

Returns me results as
Friend
Edie
Friend
Frank
Group
George

But I need it as

Friend
Edie
Frank
Group
George

Comment: Dude, PLEASE go check out these questions http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=avoid+SQL+injection

Comment: SQL injection doesn't apply here unless un-sanitized user data is in the MEMBERID session variable.  Of that you have no information either way.

Comment: +1 to counter -1. Sure it's dynamic sql but there doesn't seem to be any risk for SQL injection in this code snippet. There's no user-entered data, just a session variable that is probably a fetched pkey identifier from a login.

Comment: I can't imagine how this query can return such strings, -1 for unclear question.

Comment: imagine that you want to list the last name and address from the phone book, so you: _select Lastname, address from Book group by Lastname, address_ however when you see this you say, gee, smith appears 10k times, I only want to see it once, you have to do a query like select _Lastname from Book group by Lastname_ because you can not list the address now, because there are duplicates (on lastname), which address would you show by the last name smith? your problem is the same. if you are concerned about the name only, show and group only by the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if there is more than one REQUESTS for one of the MEMBERS you are after, you will get duplicates.

look at this:

```
SELECT --select all columns required, can produce duplicates
    R.REQUESTID, R.BYID, R.TOID, R.TYPE, R.DATEENTERED, M.MEMBERID, M.FIRSTNAME, M.LASTNAME
    FROM REQUESTS            R
        INNER JOIN MEMBERS   M ON R.BYID = M.MEMBERID
    WHERE M.MEMBERID IN (SELECT --get distinct list of members to display
                             M.MEMBERID
                             FROM REQUESTS            R
                                 INNER JOIN MEMBERS   M ON R.BYID = M.MEMBERID
                             WHERE  R.ACTIVE = 1 AND R.TOID = ___MEMBERID__
                             GROUP BY M.MEMBERID
                        )
    ORDER BY R.DATEENTERED DESC
```

Comment: I think I am gonna need to use join but I think I will need to joiN REQUESTS table with REQUESTS again.

Comment: the derived table gets a distinct list of members, I then join back to the requests in an attempt to get the other columns you want to show, which introduce duplicates.  Limit your result columns to only what you need.  if you need all of those columns, then you have to live with the duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing it to a distinct select.  I think this is provider specific, but usually

```
SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT R.REQUESTID, R.BYID, R.TOID, R.TYPE, R.DATEENTERED, M.MEMBERID, M.FIRSTNAME, M.LASTNAME"
```

or

```
SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT ROW R.REQUESTID, R.BYID, R.TOID, R.TYPE, R.DATEENTERED, M.MEMBERID, M.FIRSTNAME, M.LASTNAME"
```

Will do the trick.

Comment: if there are multiple REQUESTS rows per MEMBERS, a distinct is very unlikely to remove the duplicates.  If REQUESTS.DATEENTERED is diffeent, or REQUESTS.REQUESTID is a unique id, then there is no way a distinct will work.

Comment: its amazing, this answer is flat out wrong, yet it got 20 points, while my correct (and selected) answer only got 15!

Comment: My avatar contains a hypnotic suggestion. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Grouping by is going to give you unique values for the column by which your grouping.

Why do you want the Friend row listed twice?

Comment: Thats the thing. I dont want it listed twice but currently it is.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of fields in your SELECT and GROUP BY clauses which, from the their names, sound like either primary key values such as MEMBERID or fields likely to be very unique, such as DATEENTERED (this last one probably includes time info as well.) Any one of these fields could prevent your query from doing any kind of grouping at all. i would try removing some of these items until your grouping starts to take effect. This way you'll isolate which of the fields are problematic. Or, Keep a few fields such as first and last name and then add on to see where the GROUP BY falls apart.

Answer (score 0):

I just added a DISTINCT on the top of the query. I guessing that would solve if I got it right.

SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT R.REQUESTID, R.BYID, R.TOID, R.TYPE, R.DATEENTERED, M.MEMBERID, M.FIRSTNAME, M.LASTNAME"

SQL = SQL & " FROM REQUESTS R, MEMBERS M"

SQL = SQL & " WHERE R.ACTIVE = 1 AND R.TOID = "& Session("MEMBERID") &" AND R.BYID = M.MEMBERID"

SQL = SQL & " GROUP BY R.REQUESTID, R.BYID, R.TOID, R.TYPE, R.DATEENTERED, M.MEMBERID, M.FIRSTNAME, M.LASTNAME"

SQL = SQL & " ORDER BY R.DATEENTERED DESC"

Try this if works vote it!